# Bare React Native (React Native CLI) iOS AstroSpace custom font not being applied into <Text>

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am trying to apply a custom font into my bare React Native project into iOS platform, but it does not apply.
Previously I have applied successfully Montserrat font downloaded from google fonts.

The font is called AstroSpace and downloaded it from this link https://www.fontspace.com/a-astro-space-font-f46028

This is my react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "startMetro": "npx react-native start --reset-cache",
    "rn-packager": "npx react-native start --reset-cache",
    "rn-ios": "npx react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.38",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.6",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "MediaLibrary"
  ],
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my project folder structure for the fonts

[image: Font-Structure-Directory]

This I have tried:

- Moved the AstroSpace.ttf into ./assets/fonts/*
- Ran `npx react-native-asset`
- Ran `npx react-native start --reset-cache` to start metro
- Ran `npx react-native run-ios` failed to apply astrospace font
- Also ran `npx react-native run-ios --device "iPhone"` failed to apply astrospace font

Also Tried following:

- Renaming the .ttf to AstroSpace-Regular, Astrospace-Regular.

[image: Code-Text-With-Font-Applied]

code which I am applying the AstroSpace => https://codeshare.io/AdjPox

This is the result

[image: Font-Result-Element]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, turns out that adding the AstroSpace.ttf file in the font book in mac, then I validated it and this window popped up, and shows the internat font name is as aAstroSpace, that name I should be referencing in my  component like this

<Text style={{
fontFamily: 'aAstroSpace',
color: '#d9d9d9',
fontSize: 18
}}>
Text Example

[image: AstroSpace Font Name]

[image: Text component AstroSpace]